# Understanding Model Credibility with True/False Positive/Negative

Tags: logistic, prediction

I am currently going through a tutorial with regards to a evaluation for a Logistic Regression Model in regards to Bike Buyers (Microsoft Azure)

For the scored Model the True/False Positive/Negative come out as follows.

T/P = 3 F/P = 2 T/N =2716 F/N = 276.

So from this I can take that

- 3 people that bought bikes were predicted correctly
- 2716 that didn't buy bikes were predicted correctly
- 2 people that didn't buy bikes but the model states did were predicted incorrectly
- 276 that did buy bikes but the model states didn't were predicted incorrectly.

Overall the model predicted 2719 out of 3000 correctly.

My question is although the model did a reasonable job at predicting the data, because the target of the model is to find those that did buy bikes, I can't help but think if this was presented to a business they would focus on the 276 that were bike buyers that the model didn't predict correctly.

How would you go about explaining the model to the business?

Answer (score 1):

From your data,

Sensitivity = TP/(TP+FN) = 3/(3+276) = 1%

Specificity = TN/(TN+FP) = 2716/(2716+2) = 99%

Your classifier does a good job predicting who does **not** buy bikes (it is specific).
However it cannot predict who will buy bikes (it is not sensitive).

I am assuming that the goal was to predict who would buy (perhaps the company would like to send them a promotion). In that regards, the model was **not** useful.

**Edit 1**

Previously I explained why the business man would be correct to cast serious doubts about your model.

However, you should vary the independent parameter (threshold for logit) of your Logistic Regression.
First plot the ROC curve, and observe how trading away specificity can gain you sensitivity.

Comment: Thanks Hugues - That was a very helpful post - I adjusted the threshold to around 0.42 and that did improve the overall accuracy and the sensitivity by a couple of %. Like you I would also argue that the model is not fit for the purpose of predicting who would buy bikes. I will re-read the chapter to make sure I have understood it. Is there anything else you can suggest to improve the model?

Comment: Well, if there isn't any threshold that would give you much higher sensitivity, then I would argue that the problem lies with the feature vector, i.e. the data that you put in.

Comment: Don't forget to up-vote and accept, I'm paid in points ;-)

Comment: From your experience how high a sensitivity should you be looking for (subjective I know) ps. I tried to vote for your post but my reputation is not high enough yet :(

Comment: I would plot the ROC (receiver operator curve) of the classifier and see if it does better than random (the diagonal of that plot). If it does, then you're onto something. But the numbers can vary a lot between application. Sometimes it's better not to know anything than having predictions polluted by false positive (of lack of answers as in false negatives), sometimes any bit can help. I do medical testing and.. it depends :-)

Comment: Thanks Hugues - the ROC curve in Azure gets plotted plus the false positives etc., the curve is above the random line with an AUC of about 0.68, this is where it gets a little confusing as it is telling me it is better than random but the F/N logically doesn't sit well with me. Any advice is welcome :) thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I should have seen that. The problem is asymetric, in that many people do not buy the bike (the condition negative is prevalent). That's okay but the AUC tells you, correctly, that it is > 0.50, which is unhelpful. You're correct (but you may need to work on the model/features)